# How to get the label text of a dynamically created user control

Tags: c#

I have a user control which contains a label called `label1` , and I insert the user control into a panel using this code:-

```
        var myControl = new WindowsFormsApp4.library();
        panel1.Controls.Add(myControl);
```

So, the Label that is inside the user control will be registered into the panel.
How do I write a code that gets `label1.Text` value while the label is not generated into the panel yet?

Edit: I tried to use this code:-

```
var myControl = new WindowsFormsApp4.library();
string s = myControl.label1.Text
```

but it doesn't work because it creates a fresh user-control while the user control that is inserted into the panel value is changed in runtime.

Comment: Yiou can make the Label in the UC public. Or write a public function or property to access/set it.. And you should be able to keep the reference to the UC from creating it..

Comment: You can find your `library` control in the panel by looking at the `panel1.Controls` property

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto This can be posted as a possible answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your control in field instead of a local variable

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MyControl _myControl; // Use the real type name for your control here.

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ...
}
```

Then create it with

```
_myControl = new WindowsFormsApp4.library();
panel1.Controls.Add(_myControl);
```

and access it with

```
string s = _myControl == null ? "" : _myControl.label1.Text;
```